# How to input 1 row of data in xlsx?

Tags: python, user-input, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to create a program that takes input from the user (me) to create a catalogue of items that a customer might want to order. So far, it's been okay. But I seem to have a small problem. Instead of filling in 1 row of data per item input, it fills in 3 rows.

I've already tried removing

```
ws.write(row, col + 1, title)
ws.write(row, col + 2, cost, money)
```

But it only writes the ISBN input into the excel file.

```
#data headers
ws.write('A2', 'ISBN', bold)
ws.write('B2', 'Title', bold)
ws.write('C2', 'Cost', bold)

#data to input into cells
isbn = input('ISBN: ')
title = input('Title: ')
cost = input('Cost: ')


#starting rows and columns
row = 2
col = 0

#write it out row by row
for details in (isbn, title, cost):
    ws.write(row, col, isbn)
    ws.write(row, col + 1, title)
    ws.write(row, col + 2, cost, money)
    row += 1

#total
ws.write(row, 1, 'Total', bold)
ws.write(row, 2, '=SUM(C:C) ')

wb.close()
```

EXPECTED: Excel inputs 1 row of data per item

ACTUAL RESULTS: Excel inputs 3 rows of data per item

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your `for` loop. You are looping for each of the three items in your list. You can remove the loop if you only want to write 3 separate items once.

Or if you want to continue taking input and writing it by moving the `input()` into a loop (but make sure you add some way of exiting the loop).

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. You've made me see my code from a different perspective now. A few adjustments will be made now kind sir. Thank you again! Question will remain open if anyone else wants to give any comments.